# Is it possible to extend the "Analyze" feature of Reflector?

Tags: .net, add-in, reflector

Does anyone know if it's possible to extend the analyze functionality of Reflector?  When you select a type and click "Analyze" and then in that analyze window you get the options of "Depends On", "Used By", "Exposed By" or "Instantiated By".  I would like to get that output and send it to a file.

Thanks in advance,
Allan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a list addins for reflector [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/darrell.norton/archive/2005/03/30/60871.aspx) and the first one seems to do what you want. I have not tried it myself.

Update: A better link to codeplex for reflector add ins [link text](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins)  It includes a [file disassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) add in

The first link I posted at codebetter.com is pretty old.

Edit:

You might want to try [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) instead

Comment: Yeah, i've looked at the addins for reflector on codeplex and they didn't have what I was looking for.  I'm not looking at taking a binary and outputting the source code, what I want is to find out for a type or class, where it's been called.

Comment: You might want something other than Reflector like NDepend. Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the Analyze part of Reflector is not easily extended.  However if a all you want to get is a listing of what is shown in the Analyze tree (it is a TreeView control) ... then I maybe able to help you with this.  It sounds like it would fit nicely into the PowerCommands for Reflector project I work on (http://powercommands.codeplex.com/).

Are you just wanting to export a listing of the (unexpanded) nodes in the tree ... say under 'Used By'?  I could write a export or copy as text to output the node list as text.  Is that about what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, exactly.  When I click on a Type inside an assembly and you get the option to analyze, all that information would be awesome to be available for export.  Bonus would be the ability to export-analyze all Types in an assembly.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry it took so long, but the latest build of PowerCommands for Reflector (1.3.1) now contains a command named 'Export Analyzer Tree' - which will allow you to export the tree to a text file.  Let me know what you think (if you get a chance).